Problem when try to filter column in pandas
In this example, I'm filtering some values.
df = pd.DataFrame([{'A': -23.972176, 'B': -51.408777, 'C': np.NaN}, {'A': -23.972176, 'B': -49.959970, 'C': np.NaN}, {'A': -23.972176, 'B': -46.310840, 'C': 46.541667}])
df[df['B']==-46.310840]

When I did this, it returned the last row, as it should be.
But, I'm working in a data frame with 591624 rows × 4 columns.
The columns are Date, Latitude, Longitude, and Values.

I want to filter the specific latitude and longitude.
df[df['lat']==-23.972176]

But, when I try to filter a particular latitude, it returns nothing. This specific latitude should appear more than 1800 times.
I know that this latitude is in the DataFrame.
What could be happening?
The Latitude, Longitude, and MP10 are float64, and time is datetime64[ns].

You are running into a precision issue.  The latitudes are floats and might have extra digits that are not displayed by pandas.  You can use np.isclose or you can use .round(6) on the column before comparing.

Oh, I didn't know that! Thanks!
